# IDA Pro GDB QEMU Tricore setup

Tags: ida, gdb, qemu

I have added the lines below to IDA 6.95\cfg\gdb_arch.cfg to try to get QEMU Tricore debugging in IDA Pro, using an ARM tutorial as the basis (page 2):

https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/debugging_qemu.pdf

If I have a Tricore disassembly loaded, the debugger menu is not shown. If I have an ARM disassembly loaded, the debugger menu is shown and I can work with the options and start QEMU. The failure point is "cpu tricore" since if I change it to "cpu arm" and load an arm disassembly, the debugger menu appears and through the debugger options I can see my new entry. I just cannot get the menu to appear when a Tricore disassembly is loaded. I have tried cpu name as TRICORE and other variants including the actual CPU type, but the IDA Pro equivalent to "arm" is "tricore" as a CPU type.

```
.TRICORE_test
name       QEMU: TRICORE
cpu        tricore
area       DATA RAM     0x80000000:0xDFFFFFFF
area       IO   SYSREGS 0xF0000000:0xFFFFFFFF
initial_sp 0x08000000

cmdline    "$(QEMUPATH)/qemu-system-tricore" $(QEMUFLAGS) -M tricore_testboard -kernel "%e"
```

Comment: ARM and Tricore are pretty different, not sure why you're mentioning the ARM tutorial here or how they're "equivalent".

Comment: Thanks. I thought this might be a CPU agnostic mechanism to integrate QEMU support in IDA Pro, but from your reply it seems not. It appears that QEMU added Tricore support after IDA added QEMU support for other CPUs, but an IDA user cannot enable it for Tricore? I could write a plug in using the instruction set simulator from Infineon to enhance static disassembly.

Comment: there is some discussion on the user forums...

Comment: Thanks. I'll renew to read them if what I seek is realistic. I only use Tricore, so updates and discussion of relevance are understandably infrequent.